# Problems with Running executable in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to convert a command line tool into UI tool and I am using C# and WPF for the same.However I am blocked on one of the functionalities of the command line tool.
The problem is that after running the exe along with the arguments on the commandline, it asks for further input like Enter Password etc.

Eg:

> C:\Tool>tool.exe \abc
>
> Enter Input1 :
>
> Enter Input2 :

I am not sure how to provide this input(Input1,Input2...). There is no provision of providing inputs to tool.exe from command prompt like

> C:\tool>tool.exe  \abc <"input for parameter input1"> <"input for
>   parameter input2">

you have to enter those input manually after typing

> C:\tool>tool.exe \abc

and hiting enter.

Currently I am using the **Process** class in **System.Diagonostics** to run the process and then directly reading the output into Streamreader object.

Any suggestion on this matter will be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the command-line tool work via stdin / stdout? if so, you should be able to use a `ProcessStartInfo` with `RedirectStandardInput` = `true`, then you should have access to `StandardInput` on the `Process`. However, it would be better if the tool accepted a response file or parameters. Alternatively, you can enable `UseShellExecute` and *pipe* the inputs: `tool.exe \abc << responsefile`

Comment: Are you trying to replace `tool.exe` with a `wintool.exe`? If so, what is the purpose of using a Process class? Can you simply provide your users with a login form asking for credentials?

Comment: There is an example in [Process.StandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) that shows how to redirect input to a process.

Comment: @MarcThanks all for the reply but the problem is still unresolved for me. Even after following the example as given in  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx), I am unable to send the input correctly. In the output screen, I am seeing the following text: 
'Enter Input1:
Enter Input2:
Enter Input3:
Tool Encountered an error
Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file.Try Console.Read.'This is the same error that I was getting before I had redirected d STDIN

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process.StandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) to write to the stdin of the process.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply but the problem is still unresolved for me. Even after following the example as given in link, I am unable to send the input correctly. In the output screen, I am seeing the following text: 'Enter Input1: Enter Input2: Enter Input3: Tool Encountered an error Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file.Try Console.Read.'This is the same error that I was getting before I had redirected d STDIN